# How can I get the Cursor Position in a <code> box?

Tags: javascript, html

So I know you can get the position of the cursor in a textarea by using element.selectionStart and element.selectionEnd.
Is there a way to do something similar with `<code>`?

(I'm trying to color text written by the user. As it seems, you can only change a whole textarea's color, not certain parts. I'm using `<code contenteditable="true">` to try and fix that, but it seems to remove the possibility of reading the cursors position)

Comment: Any code you have tried? In one project I use contenteditables and I can get/set the cursor position without problems.

Comment: Code Pen or JS Fiddle?

Comment: @RyanHolton — Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. The OP should create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.